# Fade leds with serial communication Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, fastled

I am getting serial communication and trying to make an **led fade effect** ,
This is my function for leds which is facing latency issues , obviously the **for loop** . Can anyone suggest a better logic or solution to approach this without getting **latency** in leds?

```
void loop() {
    // serial communication
    while(Serial.available() > 0 ){
        int inByte = Serial.read();
        Serial.print(inByte);
        if (inByte > 0) {
            // if byte is 255, then the next 3 bytes will be new rgb value
            if (inByte == 255) {
                setColors = true;
                colorSetCounter = 0;
            } else if (setColors) {
                switch (colorSetCounter) {
                    case 0:
                        redVal = inByte;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        greenVal = inByte;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        blueVal = inByte;
                        setColors = false;
                        receiveNotes = true;
                        fill_solid(leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB::Black);
                        FastLED.show();
                        break;
                }
                colorSetCounter++;
            } else if (receiveNotes) {
                     

                controlLeds(inByte);
                       

            }
        }
    }
}

void controlLeds (int note) {
    note -= 1;
    if (!leds[note]) {
        leds[note].red = redVal;
        leds[note].green = greenVal;
        leds[note].blue = blueVal;      
    } 

    else {
   for(int i =0; i<=255; i++){       
       leds[note].fadeToBlackBy(i);
       FastLED.show();
       if(!leds[note]){
        break;       
       }
   }       
      }
   FastLED.show();
}
```

Comment: If I remember right, the main program of the Arduino runs in a loop. (I strongly assume that is for a reason.) Hence, instead making a nested a loop for the LED fading, you might have to make an update function which increments or decrements the intensity of the LED. The variable for this has to get an overall life-time for this - maybe, a global variable makes sense (yes, although global variables are considered bad style in general). Additionally, it may be necessary to involve a delay e.g. by storing the time of last update and check whether some time has passed before doing next update.

Comment: would you elaborate "latency issues"?

Comment: @Piglet yes , each note is causing a delay when there are simultaneous off events so like if I have 4 notes on then off ,  the loop will fade all on events one by one blocking other events.

Comment: What does `.fadeToBlackBy(i)` do exactly? You also mentioned a serial port, but I don't see a reference to one in your code.

Comment: @lurker just updated the code , feel free to have a look :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to write non-blocking code as Scheff mentioned. Instead of a global variable, you can use a `static` variable in a function. It remembers its value for each call of that function.

Here is an example how you could do it, using `millis()`. My code fades an LED on and off if some serialEvent happens and it does not block the rest of the code:

```
const int ledPin = 13;
int setValue = 0;
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
const unsigned long refreshTime = 200;
char buffer1[8];

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (millis() - lastTime > refreshTime)
  {
    lastTime = millis();
    fadeLED(setValue);
  }
}

void fadeLED(int fadeValue)
{
  static int currentValue = 0;
  if (fadeValue > currentValue) {
    currentValue++;
  }
  if (fadeValue < currentValue) {
    currentValue--;
  }
  analogWrite(ledPin, currentValue);

}
void serialEvent()
{ Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer1, 8);
  switch (setValue)
  {
    case 0:
      setValue = 255;
      break;
    case 255:
      setValue = 0;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
 
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , I will give you an update after testing with my setup :D